# Flask drop-down list Ajax

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, dropdown

I have an administrator page and each time when new user is added, administrator should determine group of that user (by default it will be viewer).

First, can someone please write how I can keep the default value in SQL-Alchemy?

Second, how can I update database based on drop-down list parameter?

If someone can share their own experience I will be grateful.

Comment: Your question is too bread. You should show code samples and not ask for complete solutions.

Comment: Thank you, Mohammad for comment. But I don't need entire solution. I need just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, for #1 you need to store a default value in SQL-Alchemy. If you're using Flask-SqlAlchemy then you can define a default value like this:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), default='John')
```

For SQL-Alchemy it wouldn't be much different.

And for your question #2, you need to define a controller that gets data from an Ajax call from the drop-down list and stores it in the database. I suggest using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) which has autocomplete and Ajax remote data features. As user types in the input it sends an Ajax call to the URL you define and you can get the keyword user is searching for. For a working example of Select2 you can visit [this](http://jsfiddle.net/marcrazyness/XMAq2/).

Comment: Great. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to be of help.